# Evaluate entire Haskell modules sandboxed using mueval

Tags: security, haskell

I'm trying to build a web app halfway between [tryhaskell.org](https://tryhaskell.org) and [openjscad.org](https://openjscad.org). Where a user can enter Haskell code for a module that defines  a solid object,  evaluated server side, with the resulting object displayed in the browser.

I already have an implementation of the CSG functions required.

I'd like to be able to use [mueval](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval) to safely run untrusted Haskell, much like tryhaskell.org.
I can't see how to use mueval to safely run Haskell code, including function definitions, as opposed to just evaluating Haskell statements.

I'm aware of the `--loadfile` argument to mueval, but this doesn't give the same security guarantees as mueval provides when evaluating expressions.

Is it possible to use mueval (or something like it) to safely evaluate untrusted Haskell modules?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is it possible to use mueval (or something like it) to safely evaluate untrusted Haskell modules? I'll edit the question

Comment: Yes.  Safe evaluation is the purpose of mueval.

Comment: Typical mueval usage seem to be evaluating individual expressions. I'd like to be able to evaluate an entire file, which may contain type and function definitions, while maintaining the same security guarantees

Comment: Ah sorry. You want a `hint` like api with the safety of `mueval`?  I expect this could be done quickly but do not think there is a pre-existing package or capability inside of mueval.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thanks.  It's unfortunate for me if it doesn't exist